# How to create test users in Chef, so Pedant (chef-server-ctl test) could use them

Tags: chef-infra

I am running `chef-server-ctl test` on my chef-server every once a while, to test if everything is working okay. I use output from this test to monitor the chef-server using monitoring software. But I observe that even if in config of Pedant (which `chef-server-ctl test` is using), that is located in `/var/opt/opscode/oc-chef-pedant/etc/pedant_config.rb` I have:

```
delete_org true
```

there are still some leftovers after running `chef-server-ctl test` multiple times. And by leftovers I mean organisations and users that `chef-server-ctl test` created for testing and did not delete:

```
[example@example /]# chef-server-ctl user-list
pedant_nobody_chef_26547
pedant_testorg_chef_26547_owner
pedant_testorg_chef_30029_owner
pedant_user_chef_26547
pivotal
test-26547
```

Sometimes Pedant is deleting them, and sometimes they stay not deleted after the test. I don't know what it depends on. But that's why I thought that I will disable creation of test organisation in `/var/opt/opscode/oc-chef-pedant/etc/pedant_config.rb` and instead use existing one. And I want to do the same with users. But `pedant_config.rb` is stating that it needs five different users:

```
# Test users.  The five users specified below are required; their
# names (:user, :non_org_user, etc.) are indicative of their role
# within the tests.  All users must have a ':name' key.  If they have
# a ':create_me' key, Pedant will create these users for you.  If you
# are using pre-existing users, you must supply a ':key_file' key,
# which should be the fully-qualified path /on the machine Pedant is
# running on/ to a private key for that user.

superuser_name 'pivotal'

requestors({
             :clients => {
               :admin => {
                 :name => "pedant_admin_client_#{chef_server_uid}",
                 :create_me => true,
                 :create_knife => true,
                 :admin => true
               },
               :non_admin => {
                 :name => "pedant_client_#{chef_server_uid}",
                 :create_me => true,
                 :create_knife => true,
               },
               :bad => {
                 :name => "bad_client_#{chef_server_uid}",
                 :create_me => true,
                 :bogus => true
               }
             },

             :users => {
               # An administrator in the testing organization
               :admin => {
                 :name => "pedant_admin_user_#{chef_server_uid}",
                 :create_me => true,
                 :create_knife => true,
                 :admin => true
               },

               :non_admin => {
                 :name => "pedant_user_#{chef_server_uid}",
                 :create_me => true,
                 :create_knife => true,
                 :admin => false
               },

               # A user that is not a member of the testing organization
               :bad => {
                 :name => "pedant_nobody_#{chef_server_uid}",
                 :create_me => true,
                 :create_knife => true,
                 :associate => false
               },
             }
           })
```

And I understand how to create user that will be an administrator in the testing organization (`pedant_admin_user_#{chef_server_uid}` as of now in config), how to create user that will be part or organisation, but not an admin (`pedant_user_#{chef_server_uid}`), and user that will not be a member of the testing organization (`pedant_nobody_#{chef_server_uid}`). But how to create all those users from "`:clients =>`" section, not "`:users =>`"? I mean the ones that have names:

```
pedant_admin_client_#{chef_server_uid}
pedant_client_#{chef_server_uid}
bad_client_#{chef_server_uid}
```

What does this config mean by clients and how to create them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. Pedant is not for on-going use. It's a conformance suite and is used as part of the packaging process. It is not for public use and *definitely* not for use on real Chef Server instances.

If you want to check if things are running, try `chef-server-ctl status` instead :)

Comment: I am also using `chef-server-ctl status`, more frequently, but thougth that it is a good idea to also check output of Pedant less frequently, because I thought that it would detect more subtle problems that may cause some bigger problems later. Thanks for letting me know that it's not good approach. I am quite new to Chef so I expected that answer to my question would be "you're doing it wrong" :) Out of curiosity and will to learn more about Chef - could you elaborate maybe what is "packaging process" in this context?

Comment: The packaging process is how we make the rpm or deb that you used to install chef server. As part of that we make sure that package actually works, so we hopefully don’t release entirely broken things :)

Comment: I ran `chef-server-ctl test` on an installation that's in use, should I be concerned it broke something?

Comment: @MihailKostira yes, throw the server away and make a new one